# Definition of integrability for sequences

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

My text book does not provide much about counting measures and integration. So I decided to setup integration on space $(N , P(N) , \mu_c ,R)$ myself imitating the construction of Lebesgue integral. All functions are measurable since we are considering power set.I started with simple functions which are basically sequences with finite range set.
 $$\int fd\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \mu (A_i)= \sum_{k\in N} f(k)$$
Then I defined for $[0,\infty]$ valued sequences. $$\int fd\mu=sup\{\int gd\mu : g \leq f ~~and ~g~is~simple~[0,\infty]~valued\}$$
 The above expression is simply summation of all terms since $f$ can be approached by sequence of simple non decreasing functions $f_n=fX_{(-n,n)}$ . Then for $[-\infty,\infty]$ valued sequences we define $$\int fd\mu=\int f^+-\int f^-= \sum_{k\in N}f(k)$$
So I deduced that integral of any function on $N$ is just summation of the terms of sequence of its image. $f$ is said to be integrable if $\int f^+$ and $\int f^-$ are finite. Hence $\sum_{k\in N} f(k)$ must converge .  Now here I got confused. We know that every measurable function $f$ is integrable if and only if $|f|$ is integrable. So from above construction does it imply that every convergent sequence is absolutely convergent? (We know this ain't true as there are series which are convergent but not absolutely convergent)
Where did I make fault in above imitation?

Comment: "does it imply that every convergent sequence is absolutely convergent?" No, rather, the result you mentioned is based on the fact that every series $\sum\limits_kx_k$ is absolutely convergent if and only if the series $\sum\limits_k(x_k)^+$ and $\sum\limits_k(x_k)^-$ are both (simply) convergent. (Unrelated: The title you had chosen was one of the worst ever on the site. Please be informative about the content of the post.)

Comment: Is it possible for a series to converge while either or both $\sum_k (x_k)^+$ and $\sum_k (x_k)^-$ do not converge?

Comment: Yes, try $\sum\limits_n\frac{(-1)^n}n$. (I feel an obligation to mention these are amongst the most basic facts one meets when one starts studying series.)